# Is there a good source for connectors and crimping tools needed for the individual wires?

Tags: printer-building

When I am trying to wire things in my printer I always have trouble finding a list of all the connector types and what is needed to properly crimp them. I don't see it in the pin out for the board or anything.

**Is there a good source for information about which connectors to use given a board?**

I am looking for something like a list with pictures.

Comment: This is a pretty generic question which might be better of in EE.SE. If you would post your board and ask for which connectors are used it is much more fit for 3DPrinting.SE.

Comment: Skr mini e3 v3 I guess I mainly struggle with like the difference between when is a Dupont ok to use in a jst wtf is the BL touch one etc

Comment: Also apparently some crimping tools are wider than others?